# HTML PHP Leaflet OpenStreetMaps

Tags: php, html, leaflet

I would need for a university project.
My teacher left me as a delivery, but I don't know how to do it: Displaying reports on the OpenStreetMaps map
() using OpenLayers or Leaflet framework.

Could anyone help me ?,

Thank you

WuoTizio

Comment: Welcome to the community! Unfortunately, your post doesn't contain a clear and specific question. Try reading these guidelines and editing your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It's not appropriate to ask for someone to complete a school project for you. Instead, if you're stuck at a specific part of the project, your post should include detailed information about 1. How you got to your current context/setup, 2. What results you want/expect, and 3. What results you're getting instead. Only then can someone help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For your next question, take care of what @Peter Behr said!

But to your question.
I recommend to use Leaflet, because it is realy easy to learn and you have a lot of librarys you can use.

The leaflet tutorial is very helpful at the beginning. https://leafletjs.com/examples.html

To create your first own leaflet map, you can copy the source code from https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html